# Starting. plt scripts in MacOSX

Tags: macos, gnuplot

Is there a way to start gnuplot .plt scripts directly by double clicking the script as it can be done in Windows without a problem. Right now I'm always writing the 'load' command in the terminal which sux for more files.

Comment: I don't think there is another way other than the terminal but i am not quite sure. do you use the `pause -1` command?(had to ask)

Comment: @Korpel Of course there is, simply call `gnuplot myfile`, but I don't know how to bind such a call to opening files on OSX.

Comment: @Christoph I didnt know that! Thanks for stating that out

Comment: okay I thought maybe there's an option where you could link the .plt Script to gnuplot the same way as in Windows, maybe with the automator configured right once,  what's the `pause -1` command for?